# Why is there segment fault 11

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault

I am writing the algorithm selecting kth min element, but there is a segment fault 11 reported by compiler, I wanna know what is wrong? And what causes the segment fault 11? Cause there are so many times to report segment fault 11.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int candidate(int a[], int m, int n) {
int j = m, c = a[m], count = 1;

while (j < m && count > 0) {
    j++;
    if(a[j] == c)
        count++;
    else
        count--;

}

if(j == n)
    return c;
else
    return candidate(a, j+1, n);
}

int main() {
int n, a[n],c;
int count = 0;
printf("Input the number of elements in the array:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Input the array elements by sequence:\n");

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
c = candidate(a, 1, n);
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
{
    if(a[j] == c)
        count++;
}
if (count > n/2)
    printf("%d\n", c);
else
    printf("none\n");


}
```

Comment: `int n, a[n]` : `n` is uninitialized.

Comment: "Cause there are so many times to report segment fault 11": as many times as the debugger is need to locate the exact location where it breaks.

Comment: But the truth is that I have to input n as a input. How can I initialize n?

Comment: @LeoLi initialize array after you have known n. Use `malloc` and `free` for it.

Comment: @tilz0R I get it, thank you!

Comment: There is no "array that automatically adjusts its size when an `int` variable is assigned" data type in C.

Comment: `while (j < m &&...` will always be false after `int j = m`.

Comment: @mch THX That is a stupid fault.

Comment: @mch But even if I changed m to n, the result is always 'none' as well

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize you array after you know the actual `n` value.

To initialize it dynamically, use HEAP memory and `malloc` and `free` functions together with pointers.

```
int n, *a ,c; //Declare a as pointer to array

//Get n here with scanf...

//Now reserve memory for array
a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * n);
if (a) {
    //We have our array ready to use, use it normally
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

   //Release memory after usage
   free(a);
}
```

Comment: Thx MAN ! But there remains one more question. My algorithm remains printing 'none' after I input all 1 into the array. Why does not it print out 1 as a  most element?

Comment: @LeoLi it is time to debug.